# Preparing graphics in WPF for HiDPI ("retina") screens

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm developing an application with WPF, xaml etc.

I want to make sure that my icons are ready for HiDPI screens, so I will create them at 2x their original size.

But I don't know how to use these higher resolution versions the best in XAML then. Do I manually scale them down to 50%, and if the user has his DPI set to 200%, will it use the original version of the icon? Or will it blow up the resized version?

Or, is it just necessary to put the DPI of the image internally to 192 dpi? WPF seems sensitive for that kind of things.

Comment: It would be even easier not to use images for the icons, but vector graphics (see [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.aspx)) - full resolution on every screen, perfect scaling.

Comment: I think that's a common misconception when using icons. Vector icons at small scales are most certainly NOT perfectly scaled.

Comment: As demonstrated at this link: http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2011/11/04/about-those-vector-icons.html, you can see that vector icons are still not an option. If all displays were HiDPI, maybe then. But not yet.

Comment: Fair enough, you have a point here. Still, I'd say that unless you really, *really* want to have it working 100% perfect on lower-res displays, then I wouldn't go through the hassle of manual scaling down in WPF though. Unfortunately it seems that's what you're after. We'll see, maybe someone has a working solution...

Comment: True, maybe I have to add the low-res version of the icon as well. In iOS development, this is usually done by naming convention: icon.png and icon@2x.png